# method as goal function in Microsoft Solver Foundation?

Tags: c#, optimization, ms-solver-foundation

Here is a typical optimization formulation with MSF:

```
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services;

SolverContext context = SolverContext.GetContext();
Model model = context.CreateModel();

//decisions
Decision xs = new Decision(Domain.Real, "Number_of_small_chess_boards");
Decision xl = new Decision(Domain.Real, "Number_of_large_chess_boards");

model.AddDecisions(xs, xl);

//constraints
model.AddConstraints("limits", 0 <= xs, 0 <= xl);
model.AddConstraint("BoxWood", 1 * xs + 3 * xl <= 200);
model.AddConstraint("Lathe", 3 * xs + 2 * xl <= 160);

//Goals
model.AddGoal("Profit", GoalKind.Maximize, 5 * xs + 20 * xl);

// This doesn't work!
// model.AddGoal("Profit", GoalKind.Maximize, objfunc(xs, xl));


Solution sol = context.Solve(new SimplexDirective());
Report report = sol.GetReport();
Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Is it possible to use a separate method instead of a statement like "5 * xs + 20 * xl" as goal function? For example, a method like the following? How?

```
// this method doesn't work!
static double objfunc(Decision x, Decision y)
{
    return 5 * x.ToDouble() + 20 * y.ToDouble();
}
```

Comment: Seems like `objfunc` should return a `Term` -- or maybe you just need to add the cast explicitly

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as that:

```
 static Term objfunc(Decision x, Decision y)
        {
            return 5 * x + 20 * y;
        }
```

Rather than returning a `double`, the function has to return a `Term`.

Comment: How can I use decision variables in a separate method if they are defined as a set of values like: Set setMonths = new Set(Domain.IntegerRange(1,12) , "Months"); Decision dPrice = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "Price", setMonths); I can now pass dPrice as a Decision to a method, but how can I read the individual values (like dPrice[month])? I couldn't yet find a way. Thanks

Comment: Indexed Decision variables are explained here: http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/getting-solution-values-using-solver-foundation-services/

Comment: How can I get indexed values before executing solve()? dPrice.GetDouble(i) produces an error if I call it before solve().

Comment: I would like to know this as well :-)

Comment: @Fiffe: The syntax is dPrice[i]  like a typical array index access. Consult Natan Brixius' blog via the link of my comment above.

Answer (score -1):

Note The function does not return a numerical answer, but a method to evaluate the answer. If you were to recode as 
Term Test = 5 * x + 20 * y;
String strTest = Test.ToString();

Then strTest would by something like (Add(mult(5,x), mult(20,y));